# Browse iPhoto library in photoshop or bridge

Tags: software-recommendation, photos.app, adobe-photoshop

For whatever reason you cannot browse your iPhoto library from Photoshop.

I had hoped CS6 would have added something but no. I have been looking for years and can't believe no one has written a plug in.

Best options for browsing are media browser in Finder or an app called iMedia Browser but I wanted to do it from within Photoshop or Media Bridge.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I also thought Photoshop CS6 had an little iphoto panel or something but this solution may be just as good.

It's easy to overlook but you can actually see your iphoto library when you are in the file>open... (or place...) window browsing files.

If you look on the left of the window where your home folder and other directories are, you'll find at the bottom there's a section called "MEDIA" that should have Music, Photos, and Movies. Click the photo section and the browsing window will change to a little mini iphoto browser.

I hope that helps. I'm not sure about what versions of Photoshop/iphoto this works for. I'm running Adobe CS5.5 (photoshop v5.1) and iPhoto 2011. I just upgraded to Mountain lion from Snow Leopard and it works with both those operating systems.

Comment: Note that this yields only the iPhoto preview of the shot, not the master, and there is no way to save the edits you do back to iPhoto

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. iPhoto is the Manager of the photos, Photoshop is the editor.

So you browse the photos in the Manager and then, should you wish to edit them, you send them from the Manager to the editor. This means you set Photoshop as an external editor in iPhoto.

You can set Photoshop (or any image editor) as an external editor in iPhoto. (Preferences -> General -> Edit Photo: Choose from the Drop Down Menu.) This way, when you double click a pic to edit in iPhoto it will open automatically in Photoshop or your Image Editor, and when you save it it's sent back to iPhoto automatically. This is the only way that edits made in another application will be displayed in iPhoto.

If you want to manage the photos with Bridge, then don't use iPhoto, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

found this fix to work:
http://masonsklut.com/blog/use-your-iphoto-library-in-adobe-bridge/
cheers :)

Comment: Answers on AskDifferent should be more than just a link. The idea is to have the answer stand on its own, so can you please add the essentials from the linked article to your answer? Link-only answers may get deleted.